# Tmux bind C-S-6 as command key

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

I'm migrating from Screen to Tmux. In my .screenrc I have this entry to set control-shift-6 (ie ^) as my escape key:

```
escape ^^^^
```

How do I do the same in Tmux? I tried this but it isn't working:

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-S-6
bind a send-prefix
```

Comment: Does your terminal generate different characters for C-S-6 and C-6?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
set -g prefix C-^
```